# Math for calculating percentage

Tags: variables, math, formula

I'm hoping someone will help me find a simple equation that calculates the percentage of completed tasks.

I have 3 variables:

```
$totaltasks
$remainingtasks
$completedtasks
```

Let's pretend they have these values:

```
$totaltasks  = 100
$remainingtasks = 30
$completedtasks = 70
```

In this example 70% of tasks have been completed. But that's easy to work out because $totaltasks is 100, and simply uses the equation $totaltasks - $remainingtasks

The problem is that this equation only works if $totaltasks is always 100 and $remainingtasks is always 100 or less. So as another example if my variables were like this...

```
$totaltasks  = 30
$remainingtasks = 20
$completedtasks = 10
```

...33.3% of tasks are complete, but the equation I was using would obviosuly not show the correct result.

How can I get the percentage of completed tasks when the variables change value all the time?

FYI I plan to echo the result with $percentagecomplete

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `100 * $completedtasks/$totaltasks`

This will give you the percentage of completed tasks

Comment: That gives me an error:

    Warning: Division by zero.

Would that be because some tasks have not been completed yet? (In other words $totaltask = 0)

Comment: You have to make sure $totaltask is not zero since you can't divide by zero.It's ok if $completedtasks is zero though

Comment: Update: Sorry - ignore my previous comment (delete now). I hoped to get around the division by zero issue using this code, but it always echos 0

`if ($totaltasks != 0) { $percentagecomplete = 100 * $completedtasks / $totaltasks; echo $percentagecomplete; } else { echo "0"; }`

Comment: I would double check the values you're passing in to the calculation

Comment: You're right. I accidentally mixed up a variable name. It's working now. Thanks a bunch. I learned a bit today.